# Emit an item one at a time, interact with it until a condition is met, then continue for next item

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android, android-ble, rxandroidble

I have a list of BLE devices, and am using RxJava to interact with them. I need to emit an item from the list, write a characteristic to it repeatedly until X happens, and then proceed to the next item in the list.

Current code:

```
Observable.from(mDevices)
                .flatMap(new Func1<Device, Observable<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<?> call(Device device) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "connecting for policing");
                        return device.connectForPolicing();
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void call(Object o) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "subscribing... ");
                    }
                });
```

where `.connectForPolicing()` looks like:

```
public Observable<byte[]> connectForPolice() {

        ....

        return device.establishConnection(mContext, false)
                .flatMap(new Func1<RxBleConnection, Observable<byte[]>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<byte[]> call(RxBleConnection rxBleConnection) {
                        byte[] value = new byte[1];
                        value[0] = (byte) (3 & 0xFF);
                        //Buzz the device
                        return rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(Constants.BUZZER_SELECT, value);
                    }
                })
                .repeat(3)//ignore
                .takeUntil(device.observeConnectionStateChanges().filter(new Func1<RxBleConnection.RxBleConnectionState, Boolean>() {
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(RxBleConnection.RxBleConnectionState rxBleConnectionState) {

                        return rxBleConnectionState == RxBleConnection.RxBleConnectionState.DISCONNECTING;
                    }
                }));
    }
```

This code seems to immediately emit all the items in the list, and therefore will connect and buzz all items at the same time. How can I emit items one at a time so that I may interact with them?

The pseudocode would be something like:

```
for(Device device : devices) {
    device.connect();
    while(device.isConnected()) {
        device.beep();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `flatMap` with `concatMap`

```
.concatMap(device -> device.connectForPolicing())
```

`flatMap` uses `merge` operator. It immediately emits all the items. While `concatMap` uses `concat`, that emits items sequentially. [Good article about it.](http://fernandocejas.com/2015/01/11/rxjava-observable-tranformation-concatmap-vs-flatmap/)

Comment: I gave the article a read. From my understand `.concatMap()` just preserves the order of the items, but switching my `.flatMap()` to `.concatMap()` will not cause the blocking behavior im looking for. If two items are in the list, they will both me emitted right after each other.

Comment: It will, but each item will wait until device.connectForPolicing() for pervious item completes.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, though have not yet been able to get the functionality described in the original question. At most, I can get a single device to beep, though not repeatedly. Watching my logs, it seems only 1 item is going through.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.flatMap(Observable, int)` operator.

```
Observable.from(mDevices)
            .flatMap(
                new Func1<Device, Observable<?>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<?> call(Device device) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "connecting for policing");
                        return device.connectForPolicing();
                    }
                },
                1
            )
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Action1<Object>() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object o) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "subscribing... ");
                }
            });
```

The `int` parameter is limiting the maximum concurrent operations. In this situation it will be processed sequentially.

If you want to repeatedly buzz the device until it will disconnect then changes in `connectForPolice()` function are also needed:

```
public Observable<byte[]> connectForPolice(RxBleDevice device) {

    ....

    return device.establishConnection(mContext, false)
            .flatMap(new Func1<RxBleConnection, Observable<byte[]>>() { // once the connection is established ...
                @Override
                public Observable<byte[]> call(RxBleConnection rxBleConnection) {
                    byte[] value = new byte[1];
                    value[0] = (byte) (3 & 0xFF);
                    //Buzz the device
                    return Observable // ... we return an observable ...
                            .defer(new Func0<Observable<byte[]>>() {
                                @Override
                                public Observable<byte[]> call() {
                                    return rxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(Constants.BUZZER_SELECT, value); // ... (that on each subscription will emit a fresh write characteristic observable) ...
                                }
                            })
                            .repeatWhen(new Func1<Observable<? extends Void>, Observable<?>>() { // ... which we will subscribe (the Observable.defer()) again ...
                                @Override
                                public Observable<?> call(Observable<? extends Void> observable) {
                                    return observable.delay(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // ... after 10 seconds from the previous complete
                                }
                            });
                }
            })
            .onErrorResumeNext(new Func1<Throwable, Observable<? extends byte[]>>() { // if the device will trigger disconnect then a BleDisconnectedException will be thrown ...
                @Override
                public Observable<? extends byte[]> call(Throwable throwable) {
                    return Observable.empty(); // ... in which situation we will just finish the Observable
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: I think the main issue is that in the `.connectForPolicing()` method, the `.establishConnection()` and `.writeCharacteristic()` methods are async. I need to repeatedly write the characteristic until X happens, at which point the next item can be allowed down the stream.

Comment: Yes, though I only see one item emitted down the stream, even if the list contains > 1 item, and therefore only 1 item is beeped.

Comment: When do you want to disconnect from the devices?

Comment: Well first I need to figure out how to repeatedly beep the device, but the next item in the list needs to be emitted when a particular exception is thrown.

Comment: By repeatedly you mean as quickly as possible or beeping once a second is enough? The problem lies in the `connectForPolicing()` function. I think you may misused `.repeat()` operator.

Comment: Yea, I've tried a few variations of `.repeat()` and `.repeatWhen()` though haven't yet got it working. Ideally I would write the characteristic (beep) every ~10 seconds or so. What is confusing though, is when repeating I dont want to call `.establishConnection()` again, I only want to repeat the `.writeCharacteristic()`, so I can't repeat the entire chain.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128488/discussion-between-s-noopy-and-orbit).